# trouble with math.random(), generating 10 numbers, from 0 to 100

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to generate 10 random number that go from 0 to 100, with random delay of 0 to 10 seconds. The first for loop generates 10 number that  get progressively bigger but the second loop with the timeout doesnt, shouldnt they work the same way?

```js
var index = 0;
for (index; index < 10; index++) {

  var number = Math.random() * 10 + (index * 10);
  console.log(number);
}

var index = 0;
for (index; index < 10; index++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var number = Math.random() * 10 + (index * 10);
    console.log(number);
  }, Math.random() * 10000)
}
```

Comment: Why do you declare `var index = ...` outside the loop, and then add `for(index; ...` in the head of the loop?

Comment: Log the value of `index` in the `setTimeout` example

Comment: @Andreas [It's the third most frequent JS question](https://i.imgur.com/fusvsYd.png)